# Bypass Proxy Server in vb.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, proxy, web-config

I am calling a webservice which is located on www.webservice.com. 
But due to proxy server i am not able to call.

I have used below code in my web.config but its not working.

```
<defaultProxy>
  <proxy proxyaddress="www.proxyserver.com" bypassonlocal="True" usesystemdefault="False"  />
  <bypasslist >
    <add address="www.webservice.com" />
  </bypasslist>
</defaultProxy>
```

I am using vs2005 & .Net 2.0

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex.aspx

Comment: Are outgoing connections to webservice allowed bypassing proxyserver? Normally when you have proxyserver, that is the way to open outgoing connections, otherwise a firewall may be blocking.

Comment: How have you determined that your request is hitting a proxy server? How will you know you have bypassed it successfully?

Comment: When i am accessing the web-service from Machine where there is no internet (Machines are in LAN) its working fine. But when i am trying from machine having internet connection it won't allows me.

Comment: ***bypasslist: Provides a set of regular expressions that describe addresses that do not use a proxy.***

Answer (score 5):

Use this configuration instead. Bare in mind that it is using the default credentials of your proxy. I am assuming you have already configured your proxy in the network proxy settings.

```
  <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true">
       <proxy usesystemdefault="True"
        proxyaddress="http://yourproxyAddress"
        bypassonlocal="True" />

     <bypasslist >
         <add address="www.webservice.com" />
     </bypasslist>

   </defaultProxy>
```

This only works if www.webservice.com is something that your server can reach.

Comment: `192\.168\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}` ? `[a-z]+\.webservice\.com$` ? is valid `https://www.nuget.org/api/*` ?

Comment: MSDN says: _Adds an IP address or DNS name to the proxy bypass list._. ***NOT says*** **URL or URI**.

`You should use caution when specifying a regular expression for this element. The regular expression "[a-z]+.contoso.com" matches any host in the contoso.com domain, but it also matches any host in the contoso.com.cpandl.com domain. To match only a host in the contoso.com domain, use an anchor ("$"): "[a-z]+.contoso.com$".`

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using regular expression for the bypasslist address? I think the dots in your domain could be causing a problem since dots need to be escaped in regex.

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
      <bypasslist>
        <add address="[a-z]+\.contoso\.com$" />
        <add address="192\.168\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}" />
      </bypasslist>
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Microsoft Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31465c77.aspx

In case defaultProxy setting is not used by WCF, try setting UseDefaultWebProxy to false for your web service binding in code or in web.config

```
<basicHttpBinding>
   <binding useDefaultWebProxy="False" />
</basicHttpBinding>
```

Comment: Are valid `address="https://labgrm.com/*"` ? `address="192.168.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}"` are valid, not valid `address="192.168.*"` ?

Comment: Are valid `address="https://www.nuget.org/api/*"`? or better way is **`address="www\.nuget\.org$`** ?